# Angular12 ReactiveFormsModule strange phenomenon

Tags: javascript, angular, formbuilder

Partial code：

```
@Component({
  selector: "form-test",
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <input type="checkbox" formControlName="checkbox" />{{ item.name }}
      <p>form checkbox disabled: {{ form.get("checkbox").disabled }}</p>
    </form>
  `,
})
export class FormTestComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() item: any;

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({});
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      name: [""],
      checkbox: [false],
    });

    if (this.item.name === 111) {
      this.form.get("checkbox")?.disable();
    }
  }
}
```

I'll assign a new `group` to `this.form` each time `ngOnChanges` is triggered, and I'll make the disabled property of the checkbox true when `this.item.name === 111`, but when I click on the other list items, the disabled property of the checkbox will still look like it is true, it's actually false, but the checkbox in the template renders out with `disabled=true`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGhXU.png)

[enter to demo](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/angular-form-demo-skg9tp?file=%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fform.component.ts%3A19%2C35&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpuz2b2y00073b6gj1fsj9nw%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpuz2b2x00033b6gxglstab5%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpuz2b2x00043b6gzmvymj2e%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpuz2b2y00063b6g6zp3b7op%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clpuz2b2x00033b6gxglstab5%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpuz2b2x00033b6gxglstab5%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpvzkjyv00023b6gyqz3fk9b%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A19%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A35%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A19%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A35%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fapp%252Fform.component.ts%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpvzkjyv00023b6gyqz3fk9b%2522%257D%252C%2522clpuz2b2y00063b6g6zp3b7op%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpuz2b2x00053b6g1v5mvtkn%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpuz2b2y00063b6g6zp3b7op%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpuz2b2x00053b6g1v5mvtkn%2522%257D%252C%2522clpuz2b2x00043b6gzmvymj2e%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpuz2b2x00043b6gzmvymj2e%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Comment: If no one answers here, its an angular bug, plz raise on angular github page and report this bug!

Comment: Quite weird actually, the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jynkxp?file=src%2Fform-test%2Fform-test.component.ts) here using Angular 17 works. Sound like a bug in Angular 12.

Comment: However, something I would point out that why you should create a new `FormGroup` instance when the `@Input` value changes. From my perspective, you just need to enable/disable the form control when the `@Input` value changes.

Comment: @YongShun I need to do this when developing my business, the actual functionality is much more complex

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 12, the `disabled` attribute in the form state object only sets how the control is initialized and does not bind it nor change it as the value changes.

You're initializing the form control with a value and setting its `disabled`, but when you change the value of `this.item.name`, the `disabled` attribute does not update. This is why the checkbox renders out with `disabled=true` even though the form control is actually enabled.

If so, use `enable()` and `disable()` methods of the form control to change its disabled state.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
 this.form = this.fb.group({
  name: [""],
  checkbox: [false],
 });

 if (this.item.name === 111) {
  this.form.get("checkbox")?.disable();
 } else {
  this.form.get("checkbox")?.enable();
 }
}
```

Comment: I think it's a bug, because I don't have this problem in v15 and v17